# Why String.Prototype replace doesn't work inside nested functions?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, split

I have declared in same script file the following sub-string replace function :

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character) {
    index = parseInt(index, 10);
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index + character.length);
}
```

If I use this function in the main script file (for example right after its declaration), it works properly with string output.

If I use this function inside nested functions, more exactly I have a function inside another function and I call "replaceAt" inside the second function, it doesn't work and it truncates all characters after the "index" specified in "replaceAt". I also specify that this is a content script in a Chrome extension.

Example (works okay outside functions, in main file) :

```
var h = '000000';
h = h.replaceAt(3, "1");
console.log(h);
```

Example (truncates everything after "index") :

```
function do_lut() {
    temp = '000000000000000';

    function nfu_change(e, i) {
        if (e.checked) {
            if (temp != null) {
                console.log(i + " - " + temp);
                temp = temp.replaceAt(i, "1");
            } else { temp = '000000000000000'.replaceAt(i, "1"); } 
                       }
        else { if(temp!=null) {temp = temp.replaceAt(i,"0");} else {temp = new String('000000000000000');} }
        console.log(i+" - "+temp);
        }
    }

 for(i=0;i<15;i++) 
 {
  nfu[i] = document.createElement('INPUT');
  nfu[i].type = 'checkbox';
  nfu[i].id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000000) + 1).toString();
  nfu[i].name = i.toString();
  nfu[i].onchange = function(e) {nfu_change(e.target,e.target.name);}
 }
}
```

The above will create a list of checkbox inputs and when user checks/unchecks a box, the respective index (corresponding to the input in the list) will be changed to either "0" or "1" true/false in "temp" which will be overwritten in a cookie. So, "nfu_change" is called conditionally on change of checkbox status.

Comment: This may be clearer to see what's happening if you can reproduce this as an easily runnable minimal example, perhaps using the sites Stack Snippets feature.

Comment: Post your complete code please. It can be a context problem.

Comment: How is `nfu_change()` called?  **What is `i`**?  What does `'000000000000000'.replaceAt(i, "1")` give you in `temp` (and/or what does `console.log(i + " - " + temp);` show you)?  Which `.replaceAt` is giving you an issue?  As it stands, I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: Also, is `i` a positive or negative number?

Comment: @RocketHazmat , "i" is always positive. The first console.log shows the 15-digit "temp" full of zeroes as it's initialized, but after the replace operation, everything is truncated after the index position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hypothesis is that `this` doesn't mean what you think it means.  Run your code thru a debugger and see what value `this` takes on in the places where your function does and does not do what you expect.

---

**Edit** I think that the above hypothesis is wrong.

I was able to reproduce your problem by calling your `replaceAt` function with a string for the index.

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function (index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index +  character.length);
}

alert("abc".replaceAt(1, "B")); // aBc
alert("abc".replaceAt("1", "B")); //aB
```

Here's the solution:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function (index, character) {
    index = parseInt(index, 10);
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index + character.length);
}

alert("abc".replaceAt(1, "B")); // aBc
alert("abc".replaceAt("1", "B")); //aBc
```

Comment: Unless he's using `.call` or `.apply`, then `this` will be the string that `replaceAt` was called on.

Comment: Or if the nested function is called from callback, 'this' wont be pointing at the function.

Comment: I don't know how the OP is calling `nfu_change()`, but it does look like it's an issue if `index` is a string.

Comment: At this point, I'm pretty sure that `this` isn't the problem.  It doesn't sound like he's using any code that might cause confusing behavior for `this`, and I reproduced the problem exactly by using a string instead of a number.

Comment: @mark: The `this` is *inside* the `String.prototype.replaceAt` function.  `this` is based on how a particular function is called.  Unless he's doing something other than `'string'.replaceAt()` or `temp.replaceAt()`, that's not an issue.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon yep, that parseInt was it. After the change, I just had to reload the extension in Chrome and the cookie updates correctly.